# How do you ensure a working application on checkout from your SCM when excluding sensitive files?

Tags: version-control, configuration, passwords

If you have files which contain sensitive information like passwords, I've heard it's common to exclude these files from source control. This makes sense, but it also could be confusing for a developer to checkout a copy of the source and have important files missing. Depending on what the file is, and how often its used, you might not notice the problem right away. So, how do you make these types of issues obvious to a developer when checking out a repository? Do you just shove a "readme" file in the root of your trunk? Is there a common convention for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

In the places I have worked during the years the developers normally have had full access to all files including passwords. After all they have access to the source code so if they do not have access to the passwords the built-in least resistance gene of programmers will cause them to create some kind of work around instead which could potentially be more dangerous.

If otoh you want to protect something, like the way passwords are encrypted then that part could be broken out and treated as a blackbox where only certain trusted people have source code access to. But of course it is still far from foolproof.

Personally I think one should avoid having such password restrictions for developers, passwords just be primarily for users.